# R: How to make calculations or functions from equations stored in quotes?

Tags: r

I am working on a data set (in R) in which I'm calculating weights and lengths of prey items using regression formulas that rely on a certain body part measurement, in this case OL (otolith length).

I've included an example below. I should note, the equations in columns BL_eq and WM_eq are in quotes because in real life I've `left_joined` an xlsx table containing dozens of equations, of varying complexity, using the preyTaxon column as the common denominator.

My question is: is there a way to utilize the equations within these two columns to calculate the BL (body length) and WM (wet mass) of my prey?

```
preyTaxon <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "C")
OL <- c(2, 3, 4, 1.5, 4, 6)
BL_eq <- c(rep("BL = (2*OL) + 8", 3), 
         "BL = 0.5*OL^2+2*OL+3", 
         rep("BL = 2*OL^1.5", 2))
WM_eq <- c(rep("WM = 1.5*OL^3",3), 
         "WM = 2*(BL/10)^2.5", 
         rep("WM = (10^(-5+3*log10(BL)))*10", 2))
fishy1 <- data.frame(preyTaxon, OL, BL_eq, WM_eq)
```

My hope is that I get a table with two additional columns:

```
preyTaxon <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "C")
OL <- c(2, 3, 4, 1.5, 4, 6)
BL_eq <- c(rep("BL = (2*OL) + 8", 3), 
         "BL = 0.5*OL^2+2*OL+3", 
         rep("BL = 2.2271*OL^1.5", 2))
WM_eq <- c(rep("WM = 1.5*OL^3",3), 
         "WM = 2*(BL/10)^2.5", 
         rep("WM = (10^(-5+3*log10(BL)))*10", 2))
BL <- c(12, 14, 16, 7.125, 16, 29.39388)
WM <- c(12, 40.5, 96, 0.8570224, 0.4096, 2.539632)
fishy2 <- data.frame(preyTaxon, OL, BL_eq, WM_eq, BL, WM)
```

The solution I'm considering is manually typing out a function with the equations nested in `if...else` statements, I've already tried this with some equations and have gotten the following error:

> In if (preyTaxon == "Mallotus villosus") { ... :
>     the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

So I'm not even sure if that is a good option. But if there is a simpler or more elegant way I think it could save me a lot of time, and reduce typing errors.

Thanks so much for any help you can provide!
M

Comment: Use eval(parse()).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are several approaches. (1) seems best since it uses both the LHS and RHS of each equation whereas the others specify the LHS redundantly in the code.

**1) by/within**  Using `by`, for each row use `within`, `eval` and `parse` to evaluate the equations and set their values.

```
nr <- nrow(fishy1)
do.call("rbind", by(fishy1, 1:nr, within, {
  eval(parse(text = as.character(BL_eq)))
  eval(parse(text = as.character(WM_eq)))
}))
```

giving:

```
  preyTaxon  OL                BL_eq                         WM_eq         WM       BL
1         A 2.0      BL = (2*OL) + 8                 WM = 1.5*OL^3 12.0000000 12.00000
2         A 3.0      BL = (2*OL) + 8                 WM = 1.5*OL^3 40.5000000 14.00000
3         A 4.0      BL = (2*OL) + 8                 WM = 1.5*OL^3 96.0000000 16.00000
4         B 1.5 BL = 0.5*OL^2+2*OL+3            WM = 2*(BL/10)^2.5  0.8570224  7.12500
5         C 4.0        BL = 2*OL^1.5 WM = (10^(-5+3*log10(BL)))*10  0.4096000 16.00000
6         C 6.0        BL = 2*OL^1.5 WM = (10^(-5+3*log10(BL)))*10  2.5396310 29.39388
```

**1a) by/transform** This could alternately be expressed as the following. `nr` is from above.

```
run <- function(data, eq) eval(parse(text = as.character(eq)), data)

do.call("rbind", by(fishy1, 1:nr, function(x) {
  x <- transform(x, BL = run(x, BL_eq))
  transform(x, WM = run(x, WM_eq))
}))
```

**2) split/mapply** Define a function `run` which takes a one row data frame, `data`, and an equation , `eq`, and evaluates the equation in the context of that data.

Now split `fishy1` into rows and for each row apply `run` with `BL_eq` and then again with `WM_eq`.  (`nr` and `run` are from above.)

```
spl1 <- split(fishy1, 1:nr)
fishy1a <- transform(fishy1, BL = mapply(run, spl1, BL_eq))

spl1a <- split(fishy1a, 1:nr)
transform(fishy1a, WM = mapply(run, spl1a, WM_eq)he result is:
```

**3) dplyr** Another alternative is a dplyr pipeline. `run` is from above:

```
library(dplyr)

fishy1 %>%
       rowwise() %>%
       mutate(BL = run(data.frame(OL), BL_eq),
              WM = run(data.frame(OL, BL), WM_eq))
```

**Update:** Added solutions and rearranged.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using the tidyverse, so I went with option 3 and it works like a charm